# Are there any tools that will display a complete tree

Tags: software-recommendations, family-tree

My tree currently contains around 1500 people and I would like to be able to browse the WHOLE tree; I like the way the tree displays on Ancestry.co.uk but find it a little limiting (especially when checking some of the data) that I can only see a few generations and limited number of people, in one view.

Is there anything out there, which will give me a comprehensive view of the tree?

Comment: Are you interested in all solutions or just free ones?

Comment: The ability to show all your tree depends on several things. Do you want to see just your blood relatives and their spouses? Or their relatives as well. Either way the ability to show it will partly depend on the extent to which your lines cross when cousins intermarry. You may find it impossible to show your full tree in just two dimensions.... I remember being really interested in software that should show the full tree and then finding the full view got unintelligible very rapidly

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl obviously, I would have a preference for free ones, but I don't mind paying for something, if it's going to work.

Comment: @AdrianB38 as it currently stands, there isn't anything overly complicated on my tree; no crossed lines (yet)

Comment: You may think it's not overly complicated but I'll bet it'll look disappointing if you try to view the whole thing. I've just tried to view all the descendants of one 8th grandfather - note *not* ancestors of spouses - and his grandchildren are so far apart side to side that they cannot be seen on one screen and be legible at the same time. That's simply from needing to make space on the glass for their own descendants when trying to show all the tree. I really suggest that you go for free trials and be prepared for disappointment.

Comment: @AdrianB38 thanks for the feedback and the benefit of your experience; will have a look at some of the freebie programs to see what's about (and will be cautious of spending)

Answer (score 3):

There is only one programme that I know of that will do this and that is [Family Historian](https://www.family-historian.co.uk/) However as the comments say with 1500 people in your tree this is likely to be unwieldy to view and scroll around. Pedigree Collapse also causes extra links to be shown that may also confuse the viewer.

There is a 30 day free trial available so you will be able to try it and see if it does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to view your tree as an ancestors list rather than a pedigree chart.  An ancestors list will show ALL your ancestors on one page.

Comment: Of course, it will only show ancestors and not the complete tree.